# In Tastypie, how to call Django classmethod within a Resource?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I would like to use an existing models.py filtering classmethod in my API.
The thing is I want to avoid to write the same logic twice, and want to keep logic in models (not in API). Here is what I did for now:

In models.py:

```
class Deal(models.Model):
    # some attributes

    @classmethod
    def get_filtered_deals(cls, client, owner):
        return cls.objects.filter(... # complex filtering rules here, I want to keep this logic here, not duplicate it in api.py!!!
```

But I'm stuck because I don't know how to call the get_filtered_deals() classmethod in my Deal linked resource in Tastypie. I tried something like this:

```
class Deals(ModelResource):

    class Meta(CommonResourceMeta):
        queryset = Deal.objects.all()
        resource_name = "deals"
        list_allowed_methods = ['get']
        authorization = DealAuthorization()

class DealAuthorization(Authorization):
    def read_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        return object_list.get_filtered_deals(
            owner=bundle.request.user,
            client=int(request.GET['arg2']))
```

This obviously does not work since object_list has no method named `get_filtered_deals`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

That was pretty simple...

```
class DealAuthorization(Authorization):
    def read_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        object_list = Deal.get_filtered_deals(
            owner=bundle.request.user,
            client=int(request.GET['arg2']))

        return object_list
```